# How to make Go To Definition work between projects

Tags: c#

In Visual Studio I have a C# project (A) which has another of my C# projects (B) as a reference. Is there a way to set things up so that if I click "Go To Definition (F12)" on an class/method/etc in project A that is defined in project B it will actually open the relevant source file from Project B, rather than just the metadata from Project B's assembly? I tried adding Project B to the solution, but that doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Did you add the reference before you added project b to the solution? Maybe try removing the reference, then add it again from the Projects tab.

Comment: I was going to suggest adding Project B to the Solution but you say that doesn't work.  That's very strange. Could be time to try "Turning it off and on again".

Comment: @VBDidNothingWrong, that works perfectly, thank you very much.

Comment: @StephenWilson it is *part* of the solution (no pun intended) but not the whole solution.